# Selenium Server and IE web driver for Java 8

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Previously I was using `selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0` and `IEDriverServer 2.46.0.0` (IE 11 version) for testing my web application running with `jdk 1.6`.

Now the application is compatible to run with `Java 8`. So could someone advise as to what latest version of the Selenium server and IEDriverServer can be used?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I guess you can go with Selenium 3.0 for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

IEDriverServer.exe (3.5.0.0) with Selenium (3.5.0) . That's the Latest stable version that has worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

To work with **`Selenium Standalone Server`**, **`IEDriverServer`** binary and **`Internet Explorer`** Web Browser with **`Java 8`** you need to :

- Update your system **`JDK`** and **`JRE`** with the latest version from this [**link**](https://java.com/en/download/).
- Download the latest **`Selenium Standalone Server`** from this [**link**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Download the latest **`IEDriverServer`** binary from this [**link**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.7/).
- Execute your **`Test`**.

### Current Version :

- Current version of **`JDK`** is **`Version 8 Update 151`**
- Current version of **`Selenium Standalone Server`** is **`v3.7.1.0`**
- Current version of **`IEDriverServer`** is **`v3.7.0.0`**